# Spring-Hibernate: How to submit a for when the object has one-to-many relations?

Tags: spring, forms, entity-relationship, one-to-many

I have a form changeed the properties of my object CUSTOMER. Each customer has related ORDERS. The ORDER's table has a column customer_id which is used for the mapping. All works so far, I can read customers without any problem.

When I now e.g. change the name of the CUSTOMER in the form (which does NOT show the orders), after saving the name is updated, but all relations in the ORDERS table are set to NULL (the customer_id for the items is set to NULL.

How can I keep the relationship working?

THX

---

UPDATE: Mapping Info

The Orders are mapped on the Customer side

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
@OrderBy("orderDate")
private Collection<Order> orders = new LinkedList<Order>();
```

---

UPDATE
Seems like adding a

```
@SessionAttributes("customer")
```

to my model, changing the method to

```
public String saveTrip(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {          
        this.tripManager.saveTrip(trip);
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("Form data included errors, did not save data");
        BindingUtils.logBindingErrors(result, logger);
    }

    status.setComplete();

    return "redirect:/customers/";
}
```

Could solve the issu. But is this a good way of solving it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be not to submit the CUSTOMER Object from the form.

Instead submit the customer, submit only the customers ID and the new Name. In the controller you have to load the Customer by the submitted ID and then update the Name. And persist the Customer again.

Comment: I actually pretty much like the idea of using the objects themselves and avoid the additional mapping of request parameters to the object. Isn't that the idea behind all this <form:form modelAttribute="customer"... stuff?

Comment: @Cazar In all my projects I used form specific command objects (in your case it whold contain only the ID and the Name) to avoid problems that you described, and of course because the most of my objects have fiels that must not be edided by the user in every stage or some extra service function must be invoked (sending mail) (so my apps are more than CRUD).

Comment: Yes. I have that problem, too. Not ALL fields should be editable. With using the domain object as modelAttribute is also seems that I can only use the same field names as the classes property, which shows some sort of the implementation of my code, right?

So a specific command object solves that issue, right? And probably I can also avoid some work for custom PropertyEditors?

How about validation? I do not use it yet, but will this be easier as well?

Comment: Specific command objects solve the problem: BTW: usual I implement them in the Domain/Service Layer to use them (and combine them) in several controllers. But it is a lot of monky work to write them. -- Maybe property editors are an other/better solution, but I have never tryed this nor know any solution that does it in this way -- So i have no idea (at the moment) if property editors would work or not.

Comment: And what about the @SessionAttribute solution? It solves the problem, but is it just a coincidence or meant to be like it?

Comment: What would you like to put in the session?

Comment: @SessionAttributes("customer"). That worked for me in my test and also kept all relations.

Comment: Do you do this to avoid the need of transfering the ID and loading the object?

Comment: No. I was just plaing around to solve the "lost relations" problem and stumbled over a forum post telling that this could solve that kind of problem. I did not really know what I am doing :-)

And as I am not only changing the ID and name but a bunch of other attributes as well, I thought keeping the CUSTOMER object might still be the easiest solution.

Comment: I agree using CUSTOMER is the easyesd way, as long as it works. -- I have no idea how the @SessionAttribute way works, and IMH I need to understand (at leat a bit) how something works before I use it. -- So I can not help you with the session.

Comment: Ok. But you already did by pointing to the DTO pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HI,
Make cascade="none" attribute of many-to-one relationship from order side.
Thanks.

Comment: If this works depends on the way the mapping is done. For example it would not work if the relationship is maintained by the Customer.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Then you have to make collection eager and cascade="all". But it will execute some extra queries.

Comment: I added info for the mapping. Ralph was right, the mapping is on the customer side. Not sure which code I have to change now...

Comment: I made another UPDATE to the question. I found a possible fix, but I am not sure if this is ok to do this and the right way...